# Split/Map Function in Perl to Divide Elements into Separate Arrays

Tags: perl

I am guaranteed to have a variable-length array with an odd number of elements.  The first element will always be ignored.  Every element thereafter needs to be separated into two respective arrays.  For example:

`Hello, a, 1, b, 2, c, 3` will result in the following two arrays: `[a,b,c]` and `[1,2,3]`.

Can I somehow use Perl's map/split function?  Are there any pretty one-liners?

Comment: Any particular reason you want to use perl?

Comment: Because I'm writing the rest of my code in Perl.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
( [ map $array[$_*2-1], 1..($#array/2) ],
  [ map $array[$_*2], 1..($#array/2) ] )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@c = qw(Hello a 1 b 2 c 3);

@a = @c[map $_*2+1, 0 .. @c/2-1], @b = @c[map $_*2, 1 .. $#c/2];
# or
@a = @b = (), push @{$_%2 ? \@a : \@b}, $c[$_] for 1 .. $#c;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -E'say"@ARGV[`seq $_ 2 $#ARGV`]"for 1,2' Hello a 1 b 2 c 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at this it suddenly occurs to me that if you don't care about the order, you can misuse hash creation:

```
my %hash = @array[1 .. $#array];
(keys %hash, values %hash)
```

It also makes me wonder if there is an inverse for the Perl6 Zip operator?